# How to rewrite a Python Functionality in R

Tags: python, r

How to convert the following python code into R programming?

```
def weirdFaculty(v):
    n = len(v)
```

Convert all the zeros to `-1` as the zero gives us the negative score of `-1`:

```
for i in range(n):
    if not v[i]:
        v[i] = -1

# Find the total sum

totalSum = sum(v)
currSum = 0
```

Find the point where current sum is greater than the total sum

```
for i in range(n):
    if currSum > totalSum:
         return i
    currSum += v[i]
    totalSum -= v[i]
return n
```

Answer (score 2):

The first function would be

```
weirdFaculty <- function(v) {
        v[v == 0] <- -1
        sum(v)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, the following R function `zeros_to_minus_one` does the job:

```
zeros_to_minus_one <- function (vector) {
  for (i in 1:length(vector)){
    if (vector[i] == 0){
      vector[i] <- -1
    }
  }
  return(vector)
}

vector <- c(0,1,0,1,0)
zeros_to_minus_one(vector) # Returns: -1  1 -1  1 -1
```

For the second, the following R function `find_point` does what you want:

```
find_point <- function (vector) {
  currSum <- 0
  totalSum <- 0
  for (i in 1:length(vector)){
    if (currSum > totalSum){
      return(i)
    }
    currSum  <- currSum + vector[i]
    totalSum <- currSum - vector[i]
  }
}

vector <- c(0,1,0,1,0)
find_point(vector) # Returns: 3
```